# React native - exclude compiling folder content

Tags: react-native

I am thinking of putting my folder with design files in my open source project but being afraid that they will be used within compiling for ios or android app.

Is there a way to exclude this folder?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7271#issuecomment-215375355

Answer (score 0):

If it's an open source project, I think you should keep resources in your repo and add them to your projects `.npmignore` [file](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package). This way, when you get the module via `npm install`, the resource files won't even be in `node_modules` folder and users that use your open source project won't need to change anything in their config files.

Comment: I will check this solution, thank you for the effort.

Comment: Sure. I use it in a [project](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) I maintain. This is our [.npmignore](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/.npmignore) file. As you can see we ignore the example project, tests, and everything under `.gitignore`.

Comment: Huh, I am not sure If a getting this. If I am running `npm i swimCoachStopwatch` I am getting just `node_modules` folder. I did not try any of your recommendations yet. My repo isn't meant to be a plugin, it is a self standing project with some dependencies - take a look here https://github.com/be-codified/swimCoachStopwatch

Comment: In this case, any folder you include in your project's root path won't be bundled into the `apk` and `ipa`. You can easily check this your self. Create a release apk and change the file to `.zip` (an apk is infact a zip file), unzip that file and make sure the resources are not in the apk.